# Why kestrel service won't start?

Tags: .net, apache, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I published a Blazor hosted over NET CORE app to an Apache server, defined a virtual host (reverse Proxy) and a kestrel service for the NET CORE part to work, but the server wont start.

Error:
(this is a small part of the message but it goes like this for 100 lines or so).
Also c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c897 seems to be a placeholder for the dll it should be bound to.

```
Aug 29 16:25:09 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13264]: A fatal error was encountered. This executable was not bound to load a managed DLL.
Aug 29 16:25:09 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13264]: This executable is not bound to a managed DLL to execute. The binding value is: 'c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c897
Aug 29 16:24:59 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13261]: A fatal error was encountered. This executable was not bound to load a managed DLL.
Aug 29 16:24:59 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13261]: This executable is not bound to a managed DLL to execute. The binding value is: 'c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c897
Aug 29 16:24:49 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13256]: A fatal error was encountered. This executable was not bound to load a managed DLL.
Aug 29 16:24:49 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13256]: This executable is not bound to a managed DLL to execute. The binding value is: 'c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c897
Aug 29 16:24:38 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13254]: A fatal error was encountered. This executable was not bound to load a managed DLL.
Aug 29 16:24:38 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13254]: This executable is not bound to a managed DLL to execute. The binding value is: 'c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c897
Aug 29 16:24:28 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13252]: A fatal error was encountered. This executable was not bound to load a managed DLL.
Aug 29 16:24:28 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13252]: This executable is not bound to a managed DLL to execute. The binding value is: 'c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c897
Aug 29 16:24:18 e4334f0186.servercheap.net dotnet-mycoreapp[13250]: A fatal error was encountered. This executable was not bound to load a managed DLL.
```

If this is not a common issue I can post the service and the Virtual host code.
Seems more like a VisualStudio Publish misconfiguration rather than Apache being misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a non-modified app host executable got copied to your publish output somehow. Try cleaning the `/obj` directory before publishing in your host, should resolve your issue [Ref](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35628)